# How to dynamically update a HTML page and associated images of a HTML5/Javascript smartphone app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am working on a HTML5/Javascript based smartphone app. I planned to use PhoneGap/others and was thinking to bundle all my HTML pages as app for the smartphone. If that is the case, I would assume I do not need to maintain any server for the html pages of the app.

Provided that assumption is right, I have few HTML pages that players will be using in their smartphone. One of the pages requires monthly update of the content and associated images.

Can you point me to a direction how can I monthly update the content and images of that single page on players' smartphones?

Answer (score 0):

To update the content on the pages, you will either need to utilize a database where you can update the values which you then have queries in place to pull and display on your pages.

Alternatively you will need to update the pages with the new content and then redeploy over the platforms you decide to go with.

Comment: Hi Daniiel, thanks. As indicated earlier, we do not want any server component like database. Thus, your second suggestion is something what we are thinking. We could simply replace the page with newer version. But in that case, how can we update a page in client's smartphone? Could you please explain little bit more on your redeploy concept?

Comment: How it works is, you would update the project as you normally would. Change the information on the pages you wish and then you would use cordova / phonegap to compile to the platforms you want and upload to the app stores. The new version will be pushed onto the clients phones automatically.